# drop down menu and seo

Tags: seo, menu, drop-down-menu

"Hidden links and contents are not good for seo". Whether drop down menu affects seo. If yes any perfect solution for drop down menu with seo perspective?

Comment: related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81684/seo-friendly-links-inside-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 3):

drop down menus are not "hidden" in terms of SEO. If the drop down menu is rendered in standard HTML then any bot will be able to "see" it. Now, if you are using Javascript to create your drop down menu, that is a different story - most bots don't currently execute Javascript. From an SEO perspective, you may just want to make sure that the keywords you use in your drop down menu are appropriate for your site and the audience you are targeting. If they are not, then you may want to consider rendering the dropdown in Javascript. Hope this helps

Comment: Any browser can read HTML but external css or js defines display property in most of the cases.

Comment: As long as you are using standard HTML then the search engine robots will be able to see it. You can use external css and/or js to define the display property, but again, as long as the html is rendered to the page you will be good in terms of robots being able to "see" the drop down menu (view source to verify)

Comment: I'm not sure this is completely correct anymore ( this answer was 2 years ago so I thought I'd add in this updated note for current viewers). I'm sure everyones all seen the google 'preview' where it attempts to show you where, visually, on the page it saw your search terms. I'm sure this is done with a screen reader and an OCR as a deeper level of integrity in the algorithm. It would be odd for them to have this technology and for it not to be represented in their search ranking mechanic

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about CSS driven drop down menus? Don't worry, they are SEO friendly and will be treated as normal static links regardless of how they are displayed.

Javascript however hasn't been conclusive whether it is really SEO friendly or not. I've had my experiments and it is really hit or miss so I can't really say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is best to keep things simple. Search engines still do not read JavaScript very well. If your site navigation is based on JavaScript, it will be difficult to get all of your pages indexed. If the decorative drops down type menus are important to you, always provide a back up of plain text links. I suggest you should make a site map for google crawler bot.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your page source. If your drop down menu is standard HTML with the links specified by `<a href="...">` tags, then it's fine.

Google may not find the links if you use Javascript to generate the menu/links. Same goes if you use a `<select>` element, which I've seen a lot.

Comment: I've also been told not to use `<select>` to build menus because it's supposed to be not so SEO friendly. Do you have any pointers that back up this claim? It's quite surprising because `<select>` is a standard HTML tag that has been in existence for the longest time. Thanks!

Comment: @Siku `<select>` is a standard HTML element, but not for links. It's for selecting an item in a form. Any navigation under `<select>` elements uses Javascript which search engines generally don't parse.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue for the Google bot to potentially confuse drop down menus with hidden links - particularly if the code is something like:

```
< div id="menu1" style="visibility: hidden;">< a href="">Home< /a >< /div>
```

Its an AI complete problem to detect if that kind of code is designed to trick or not, so there will always be occasional issues.
However, any popular menu is likely to be ok as someone else would have filed a reconsideration request if there was a noticeable issue. Also remember that there are many trust factors, so the effect may be subtle.