# SEO-Friendly <ul>-Based Drop Down Menu

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, seo

There have been some good discussions whether using the HTML standard `<select>` tag to generate menu / links is SEO friendly.

- [drop down menu and seo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2971661/583539)
- [Is using a select list for navigation SEO Friendly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3071838/583539)

Looks like the general consensus is it's not an SEO-friendly method.

Do you guys know a good jQuery plug-in that "transforms" a regular `<ul>`/`<li>` combination into a drop down menu that behaves just like `<select>`?

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/destination-a">Link A</a></li>
  <li><a href="/destination-b">Link B</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Tyler Crompton: Either one is fine. Thanks.

Comment: In HTML 5, you can achieve the same effect with what I assume is SEO-friendly with something like `<nav><a href="/destination-a">Link A</a><a href="/destination-b">Link B</a></nav>`

Answer (score 0):

[MenuMatic Menu](http://greengeckodesign.com/menumatic) is expecting an object of type `ur`, but it is of Motools, but you can integrate it with JQuery using jQuery `noConflict` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with li menus is that while they are the easiest way to get a functioning menu that can have great effects you can't easily have an alt tag n the background image for the menu item.

You will need to build a transparent gif and overlay the base image that css provides, this image can then get a traditional alt attribute in the image tag. That would be seo friendly. Its a shame google works like this as I never condone coding for the sake of this, its imagining all the extra code across the www for nothing.

Google should be able to work out what is a good page much better than this IMO.